# Find The X In This Shape.

Tags: geometry, triangles

This is a rather weird shape that even my teacher couldn't solve. (Lets ignore the faulty touchscreen)

The red letters are the angles and A.C.E are perfectly straight (Colinear)

Is there an way to solve this question? The answer is 2 but we couldn't find it.

I am just an early high schooler.

[image: Weird Shape]

Comment: I find it impossible to understand those red ...signs?....letters? in the picture. I though *think* they are connected somehow to those two red angles. Describe this clearly. Also, does "being level" mean there are collinear?

Comment: @DonAntonio the red letters are angles and the A,C,E points are perfectly level so colinear according to the dictionary (English isn't my first language.)

Comment: @DonAntonio by level I meant straight.

Comment: English also isn't even my second language. Anyway, I didn't mean the symbols for "angles" but those signs...like "44" or something, and that thing to the right of the angle symbol below C...I just cannot understand that.

Comment: @DonAntonio it was supposed to be 45 and 135 but damn 65 inch laser toucshreen and bad program.

Comment: Have you learned about the law of cosines?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout negative but the test book still had this question anyway. (Turkey doesn't have the best ed system in the world anyway.) but at least I have pythagoras and "öklid theorem"

Comment: @JonathanIrons Are you sure that's the right name of the theorem? [Öklid teoremi](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96klid_teoremi) is Euclid's theorem, which is about [number theory](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Say%C4%B1lar_teorisi), not geometry.

Comment: Regardless, use the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) on the triangle $CBE$, as Cansomeone suggested. The Turkish Wikipedia version of the article is good, if you struggle with the English version.

Comment: @Jam damn translations... This is the one calculating the triangles height by using the sides etc https://www.google.com/search?q=%C3%B6klit+ba%C4%9F%C4%B1nt%C4%B1s%C4%B1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw187Xz5PiAhUKyKYKHYA_DP4Q_AUIDigB&biw=1366&bih=625  I dont know the english name though.

Comment: @Jam thanks for the link and the answer. My English is kinda decent.

Comment: @JonathanIrons I see. I think that would be the [geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem) in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct triangle $DEB$. The sides $DE=BE=10, DB=12$ (Pythagorean theorem). Let $O$ be point of intersection of $AE$ and $DB$. Then  $EO$ is the height in isosceles $\triangle DEB$. 
We also know that the diagonals of square bisect so $OB=OC=6$. Thus, $EO=\sqrt{10^2-6^2}=8$.

Finally, $x=EO-OC=2.$